# rosbuild error during ros install mac osx 10.6.6

Tags: rosbuild, rosinstall, macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

on a Mac OSX 10.6.6,

I had the following error for ros install command:
rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=ros-full&overlay=no"

what went wrong?
[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system dependencies
[ rosmake ] Starting >>> tools/rospack
[ rosmake ] Finished <<< tools/rospack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 20 linesoslib: 0.7 sec ]              [ 1 Active 1/68 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package roslib
[rosbuild] Including /Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/bin/rosboost-cfg", line 35, in 
rosboost_cfg.main()
File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/tools/rosboost_cfg/src/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 328, in main
raise BoostError("Cannot find boost in any of %s"%search_paths(options.sysroot))
rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError: "Cannot find boost in any of [('/usr', True), ('/usr/local', True)]"
CMake Error at /Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:848 (message):
rosboost-cfg --include_dirs failed
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:5 (rosbuild_add_boost_directories)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package roslib written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/paulogoncalves/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110317-103414/roslib/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib [FAIL] [ 0.78 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosemacs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosemacs  No Makefile in package rosemacs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosboost_cfg [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosboost_cfg  No Makefile in package rosboost_cfg
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package roslib.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbash [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbash  No Makefile in package rosbash
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 5 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /Users/paulogoncalves/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110317-103414
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in 
pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 442, in run_script
self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1167, in run_script
exec script_code in namespace, namespace
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 547, in rosinstall_main

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 462, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/paulogoncalves/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9457/rosbuild-error-during-ros-install-mac-osx-10.6.6/) by [paulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/296/paulo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-17**:
Duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/401/help-on-install-ros-in-a-macbook-with-osx-1066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/401/help-on-install-ros-in-a-macbook-with-osx-1066

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem also happened for me on 10.7 with Macports. I found the correct solution to be defining CPATH and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH. So run the follow bash script prior to running 'rosinstall'.

```
PORTS=/opt/local
export CPATH=$PORTS/include
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:$PORTS/lib
```

---

Originally posted by [zmoratto](https://answers.ros.org/users/1543/zmoratto/) with karma: 11 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1